# How to access data fields in Vue from async method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Code:

```
export default {
   data() {
        return {
            nameCity: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        findCity(event){
            event.preventDefault()
            findCityCust().then(function(response) { 
                console.log(response)
               this.nameCity = response;
            })
        }, 
    },
}
```

And here - this.nameCity = response; - throws an error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

How to work with fields from asynchronous methods in Vue 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard function is not binded to component, try arrow function:

```
export default {
   data() {
        return {
            nameCity: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        findCity(event){
            event.preventDefault()
            findCityCust().then((response) => { 
                console.log(response)
               this.nameCity = response;
            })
        }, 
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the error is caused by `this`

[differences-between-arrow-and-regular-functions: this value](https://dmitripavlutin.com/differences-between-arrow-and-regular-functions/#1-this-value)

in `function(){}`, `this` is the global object

in `() => {}`, `this` is the current Vue instance

so change it to

```js
findCityCust().then(response => { 
    console.log(response)
    this.nameCity = response;
})
```

or

```
methods: {
    async findCity(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        this.nameCity = await findCityCust();
    }, 
},
```